# Embedding PDF with flipping pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I've seen a lot of questions and answers here that help you too embed PDF documents, but they are all "vertical read", where you scroll down to see other pages.

Is there any plugin, or maybe even a simple script that would help you to embed and read the PDF document horizontaly? Like where you see two pages and click next on top to see the next two.

Just like a book. (No fancy animations though)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that lets you read pdf documents. But they might be fancy.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/

or

http://fliphtml5.com/free-pdf-to-jquery-flipbook.php

I like the last one especially

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial view of a PDF to show two pages.

If you add Fullscreen view to that, and the user has not deactivated clicking to the next page, it actually should give the effect you want (not verified).

If the Fullscreen view does not work, your user would use the cursorLeft and cursorRight buttons to navigate.

Comment: what method I would use in this case to embed the PDF and how do I set the initial view to two pages?

Comment: You set the initial view in the Document Properties dialog in Acrobat. That's also where you would set the Fullscreen view on opening. As these settings are now document properties, you won't need any special plug-in to embed; embed the document as you would embed any other PDF.